# Approve request for drive file access programmatically

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I have a requirement where a user having read access to a file (google native docs) can access for edit access to the drive file (from google drive UI) since the owner of the file would always be known to us (A account not operated by human). Do we have any API in google drive or g suite admin where we can fetch the pending requests for granting access to a given file?

Comment: I am not really sure i understand your question.  However the only way to see who has access to a file is to check the permissions on that file. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list.  You can also see who has made changes in the file using https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list

Comment: Hi @DaImTo thank you for the reply, i will elaborate my ask, I have a scenario where a user from google drive having read access to the file will ask for edit access for the same, since the owner of the file would be a non human account(not operated by any user) i need to grant the user edit access to that file for which he has made a request to me.So for the same purpose do we have any api in gsuite/drive/admin where i can fetch whosoever has requested for the access to the file using an API.

Comment: I dont think you can do that.  Requests for access are normally sent to the email address of the owner of the file.  Assuming you are using a service account it doesnt have an email account for things to be sent to.   If it isnt a service account and you are using a normal oauth account you could check the email but i am not sure if you can figure out how to click the link to approve the user or not.   Its an interesting use case i would love to hear if you get it working though.